# php error when removing product from cart - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've set up a Woocommerce store and all is working as I'd expect apart from when you remove an item from the basket this error is displayed:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /mysite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/title.php:15)
>   in /mysite/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
>   1196

I've checked functions.php for any spaces above and below the php to no avail. Can anyone shed any light on a possible culprit and how I might resolve the issue?

Comment: What is the code on like 15 of title.php and line 1196 of plauggable.php?

Comment: Line 15 of title.php:
        <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

Comment: Line 1196 of pluggable.php:  header("Location: $location", true, $status);

Comment: Ok so by the looks of it, you are outputting HTML in title.php and then trying to set a header after in pluggable.php.

You cannot output before setting headers... sorry I cant tell you how to resolve it without seeing the complete code but I hope this helps you figure out the logic as to why you are trying to set headers afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue.

I had created a series of hooks in the functions.php file which were causing a number of store wide conflicts. Removing them fixed everything.